# Sorting posts in a customized order

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a "custom Page" set up and I am trying to figure out how I can make it arrange the posts it pulls in a specific order...I am thinking of using the custom fields. But not sure how to add a listing of a numeric value.

- For Lease and For Sale
- List item Size List item (ie 1 br, 2br, 3br) (least expensive
  first)
- List item Price (Cheapest to most expensive)

Answer (score 0):

You can order order posts by [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). The query will be something like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'custom_page', 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price' ) );
```

In your case, you will have to convert price and size to pure numeric values for the sorting to work. For Lease and Sale, I would suggest you should not rely on sorting but use it to query, something like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom_page', 'meta_key' => 'deed', 'meta_value' => 'lease' ) );
```

Comment: hey could i pay $30 or $40 to help me get this in a wordpress file?

Comment: @phill mail me at akshay[dot]raje[at]gmail[dot]com